# How to replace special charachters in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, nltk, sql-function

I am fairly new to Pyspark, and I am trying to do some text pre-processing with Pyspark.
I have a column `Name` and `ZipCode` that belongs to a spark data frame `new_df`. The column 'Name' contains values like `WILLY:S MALMÖ, EMPORIA` and `ZipCode` contains values like `123 45` which is a string too. what I want to do is I want to remove characters like `:`, `,` etc and want to remove space between the `ZipCode`.
I tried the following but nothing seems to work :

```
new_df = new_df.withColumn('Name', sfn.regexp_replace('Name', r',' , ' '))
new_df = new_df.withColumn('ZipCode', sfn.regexp_replace('ZipCode', r' ' , ''))
```

I tried other things too from the SO and other websites. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`[,|:]`** to match `,` or `:` and replace with space `' '` in **Name** column and for **zipcode**  search for space `' '` and replace with empty string `''`.

**`Example:`**

```
new_df.show(10,False)
#+-----------------------+-------+
#|Name                   |ZipCode|
#+-----------------------+-------+
#|WILLY:S MALMÃ–, EMPORIA|123 45 |
#+-----------------------+-------+
new_df.withColumn('Name', regexp_replace('Name', r'[,|:]' , ' ')).\
withColumn('ZipCode', regexp_replace('ZipCode', r' ' , '')).\
show(10,False)
#or
new_df.withColumn('Name', regexp_replace('Name', '[,|:]' , ' ')).\
withColumn('ZipCode', regexp_replace('ZipCode', '\s+' , '')).\
show(10,False)
#+-----------------------+-------+
#|Name                   |ZipCode|
#+-----------------------+-------+
#|WILLY S MALMÃ–  EMPORIA|12345  |
#+-----------------------+-------+
```